# How to install animation addon plugin of compiz in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: unity, 16.04, compiz, 16.10

The compiz in Ubuntu 16.10 has animation addon plugin which contains burn and other cool effect. My system is ubuntu 16.04 , and compiz lack of these effects. Is it possible to install new effect from a latest compiz for ubuntu 16.04 ?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, simply go to your terminal and run this command:

```
sudo apt install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins-extra
```

...then open the compiz configuration settings manager and the effects should show up.

Comment: It doesn't work. I have already had these latest packages and can't find animation addon plugin  We can only install compiz 0.9.12.2 in ubuntu 16.04, but  only compiz 0.9.13.0  in ubuntu 16.10 have these plugins.

Comment: Well, you answered your own question... it's not available until 16.10. Cheers, Al

Comment: I hope it is possible to build compiz from source to install the new plugin. I tried to make it but I failed